# Direct paths throws 404

Tags: firebase, nuxtjs3

I have a simple app that I'm running with few navigations in the nev bar.
I can click through the nev bar and navigate the app but if I go directly to the path (i.e. mysite.com/home or mysite.com/about or mysite.com/helloworld) then the app throws 404 error. This behavior is only happening in production when I deploy the app through firebase.

Here is my firebase config

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": ".output/server",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "site" : "<firebase-project-id>",
    "public": ".output/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "server"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Here is my Nuxt3 config

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  meta: {
    title: '<title>',
    meta: [
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: '<description>',
      }
    ],
    htmlAttrs: { lang: 'en' },
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: '/favicon.ico'
      },
      {
        rel: 'preconnect',
        href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
        crossOriginIsolated: true

      },
      {
        rel: 'preconnect',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100;400&family=WindSong&display=swap'
      }
    ],
    css: ['@/assets/css/main.css'],
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    'public': {
      FIREBASE_API_KEY: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
      FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      FIREBASE_APP_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
      FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
    }
  },
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: {
          tailwindcss: {},
          autoprefixer: {},
        },
      },
    }
  },
  ssr: false
})
```

I'm only deploying a static app (`.output/public`) and not the server portion, so not sure if the issue is related to that or something else.

A tagalong question would be, any idea on how to create a firebase functions integrated with nuxt's Nitro Engine so I can enable SSR?

Appreciate the help here.

Comment: Did you tried that one? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/deploy/presets#supported-hosting-providers

Comment: Also, you can try to host it on Netlify for debugging purposes. It work well there without any further configuration.

Comment: I did, but it hasn't worked so far. I suspect that the reason is that I'm deploying the server to cloud functions, so it probably doesn't have any idea on how to find routes. At this point I've moved on to pure Vue3 project